# RDP support in unity

Tags: unity, remote-desktop

Is there any support yet for remote desktop protocol in Ubuntu Desktop yet? - I need to give access to >100 users in an AD domain and I would rather not have to install VNC clients. I know RDP is supported in other desktops but that is not what they want to use.

Comment: I would really like to see this, too. Remote desktop should be a first class citizen in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04 desktop (and several previous versions have as well) comes with [Remmina Remote Desktop Client](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) pre-installed, and it supports connecting directly to RDP clients, such as windows. I have used to connect to Windows 7 machines without any difficulty.

You could try it out from the livedisk version of Ubuntu Desktop if you want to verify it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Afforess, but isn't this a client for Ubuntu? - I'm looking for the something on Ubuntu that will allow RDP from the built in client on Windows, specifically to Unity Desktop

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you meant running a RDP server on Ubuntu. You can install xRDP, it is essentially a proxy between RDP and a local VNC session.